# How to link an answer to a specific question with exercise package?

Tags: cross-referencing, exercises

I am typesetting some exercises with the following structure,

```
Exercise 1
Some introductory text.
1.1 The first question?
1.2 The second question?
```

Using the exercise package I can accomplish this in the following way,

```
\begin{Exercise}
    Some introductory text.
    \Question The first question?
    \Question The second question?
\end{Exercise}
```

Now I want to type an answer to each question. 
The only way I found to do this is by setting the numbering myself in the answer,

```
\begin{Answer}[number=1.1]
    The answer to Question 1.1.
\end{Answer}
\begin{Answer}[number=1.2]
    The answer to Question 1.2.
\end{Answer}
```

which will eventually fail when the order of exercises/questions changes.

What is the right way of doing this?

How can I link an individual answer to each of the questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ref=<ref>` or `number=\ref{<ref>}` key when you `\label` the questions of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}% http://ctan.org/pkg/exercise
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
    Some introductory text.
    \Question \label{first}The first question?
    \Question \label{second}The second question?
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}[ref=first]
    The answer to Question~\ref{first}.
\end{Answer}
\begin{Answer}[number=\ref{second}]
    The answer to Question~\ref{second}.
\end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As alternative a quite elegant solution by the excellent »[exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)« package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[load-tasks=true]{exsheets}

\settasks{
  counter-format=qu.tsk,
  item-indent=3em,
  label-width=2em
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
  \begin{question}\label{qu:twopart}
    Some introductory text.
    \begin{tasks}
      \task The first question?\label{qu-1:twopart}
      \task The second question?\label{qu-2:twopart}
    \end{tasks}
  \end{question}

  \begin{solution}
    \begin{tasks}
      \task Solution to question \ref{qu-1:twopart}.
      \task Solution to question \ref{qu-2:twopart}.
    \end{tasks}
  \end{solution}

  \printsolutions
\end{document}
```

---

[image]